# Can't remove undesired trailing whitespace from variables used in slurm shell script that cause 'cd' to fail for too many arguments

Tags: bash, shell, sed, slurm

I am running code someone else developed to automate a process. It fails at the 'cd' step because a space is being inserted into the path its trying to generate. This is the whole shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --mem=0 
#SBATCH --job-name=phase_2

t_nod=$2

file_path=`sed -n '1p' $3/$4/logs.txt`
protein=`sed -n '2p' $3/$4/logs.txt`

morgan_directory=`sed -n '4p' $3/$4/logs.txt`
smile_directory=`sed -n '5p' $3/$4/logs.txt`


python jobid_writer.py -pt $protein -fp $file_path -n_it $1 -jid $SLURM_JOB_NAME -jn $SLURM_JOB_NAME.txt

cd $file_path/$protein/iteration_$1
mkdir sdf
for f in smile/*
do
   tmp="$(cut -d'/' -f2 <<<"$f")"
   tmp="$(cut -d'_' -f1 <<<"$tmp")"
   if [ $tmp = train ];then name=training;fi
   if [ $tmp = valid ];then name=validation;fi
   if [ $tmp = test ];then name=testing;fi
   echo "#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 1

echo \$1
echo \$2
echo \$3
oeomega classic -in \$1 -out sdf/\$2\_sdf.sdf -maxconfs 1 -strictstereo false -mpi_np \$3 -log \$2.log -prefix \$2">>$name'_'conf.sh

   sbatch -J $SLURM_JOB_NAME -c $t_nod $name'_'conf.sh $f $name $t_nod
done
wait

scancel $SLURM_JOBID
```

The script reads two variables from a log file:

```
file_path=`sed -n '1p' $3/$4/logs.txt`

protein=`sed -n '2p' $3/$4/logs.txt`
```

later the script wants to cd to that directory like so:

`cd $file_path/$protein/`

However, the script fails because for some reason, a trailing whitespace is added for the $variables so cd fails for too many arguments.

If I insert this into the script:

`echo cd $file_path$protein`

I get:

`cd file_path protein`

But I would expect to get

`cd file_pathprotein`

Things I've tried

1. checking that log file for any trailing whitespaces (there are none)
2. i tried adding quotes to the variables like

`echo "$file_path$protein"`

but that makes it even worse, now there are tab spaces between the variables when it is echo'd

3. i tried adding quotes around the sed line, like so

file_path='`sed -n '1p' $3/$4/logs.txt`'

but then this caused two issues, one is that the variable became

`$3/$4/logs.txt`

when the script called it in the python part later AND it still had extra spaces in the cd command.

I consulted these two SO articles:

[Bash: use cd command on a variable including spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820673/bash-use-cd-command-on-a-variable-including-spaces)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361887/how-to-escape-whitespace-in-variable-passed-to-cd

And couldn't get these solutions to work. Partly because they didn't match my problem exactly and partly because I am very confused as to what is going on.

Comment: Why are you escaping `$1`, etc. as in `echo \$1`? You should copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about (as the `bash` tag you used instructs) then [edit] your question to replace the existing code with the corrected version and let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: Always double quote your variable references.  So `cd $file_path/$protein/iteration_$1` becomes `cd "$file_path/$protein/iteration_$1"`.  Your extra whitespace comes from one of the `sed` commands you set $file_path or $protein with.  Add a couple `echo` statements to see which.  Ex `echo ">>>>$file_path<<<<"`.  It will show you if you have whitespace somewhere in the brackets.  Or, use `#!/bin/bash -x` on top of your script for a full debug.